# Is there a plugin that creates a WP post based on a Twitter account's hashtag?

Tags: posts, twitter

I've found a myriad of plugins that tweets my posts or grabs tweets into a widget, or posts all tweets, but none that:

1. looks for a specific twitter @account's #hashtags and
2. creates a WP post
3. in a custom category `Tweet` (when specific #hashtag shows up)

So Wordpress will look at Twitter @username tweets, doing nothing, waiting for a trigger in the form of the hashtag `#foo`. Then Wordpress will create a post in the category `bar`.

Is there a plugin that does this, or will I have to code a function myself? Which I doubt I'll be able to do :/

Comment: Do you want post per tweet? or not bothered with tweets grouped by day.

Comment: Yes, post per tweet, but only when tweet has a specific hashtag.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way of doing this is to use a slightly undocumented feature of twitter's search - you can pull an Atom feed for any search query (which includes hashtags), and then use FeedWordPress to generate posts.

A sample Twitter search query that returns Atom (which is is an alternative to RSS and works in the same way):

```
https://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=%23cricket
```

Use [FeedWordPress](http://feedwordpress.radgeek.com/) to create posts in whatever category you want from the twitter hashtag feed.

To set a category do the following: [(from the FeedWordPress FAQ)](http://feedwordpress.radgeek.com/wiki/how-do-i-add-category-or-tag-posts-particular-feed):

- Log in to your WordPress Dashboard using your administrator username and password.
- Go to the FeedWordPress administrative interface by clicking through to the Syndication page.
- Pull up the Categories & Tags settings page for the feed whose posts you want to apply the category or tags to. The easiest way to do this is to go to the "Syndicated sources" table and hover your mouse over the source that you want to work with. Several options should appear underneath; click on "Settings > Categories & Tags."
- To add one or more categories to any posts that come in from this feed, scroll down to the Categories box on the Categories & Tags Settings page, There should be a selection box marked "All posts: Give all posts from this feed these categories." You can check whatever category or categories you want. To add one or more tags to any posts that come in from this feed, scroll down past the Categories box to the Tags box; there should be a text box marked "Tag all posts from this feed as..." Type in one or more tags, separated by commas, and mash the "Add" button to apply them.
- When you've finished adding Categories and Tags, mash the "Save Changes" button at the bottom of the page.

Comment: This looks promising, I'll try it out.

Comment: The feed is coming in, but I can't for the life of me make it set the posts into the correct category.

Comment: @eyestein - I've updated the answer with instructions for setting a category.