# Tweets based on Twitter hashtag into a pending WP post

Tags: twitter, workflow

If a twitter user sends out a lot of content during the day, not all of their followers see it. It'd be good to have a way to 1) curate those links for followers 2) get more traffic back to your site

Are there plugins or hacks to take tweets from a specific hashtag and dump them into a pending WP post? Further, what if you took tweets from a specific hashtag and a specific user (in case that hashtag gets spammed).

At the end of the day, they'd login to the site, organize/clean up the links & titles and then publish.

Any ideas on how one could do this? This answer [Is there a plugin that creates a WP post based on a Twitter account's hashtag?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20807/is-there-a-plugin-that-creates-a-wp-post-based-on-a-twitter-accounts-hashtag) seems somewhat similar, but i don't want to create a post for each tweet - just aggregate links.

Any help/advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I found RSS digest http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rss-digest/ which will work for me.